# Flattening/Merging/Composing/Combining two sequential function (signatures) into one?

Tags: c++, functional-programming

This question is to find out what the name of this operation is in science and the programming industry.

```
how_is_this_called(f1(x1, x2), f2(y1, y2, y3)) -> f(x1, x2, y1, y2, y3)
```

I'm looking for the name of the operation which takes two functions and returns a function where the parameters are concatenated. The returned function will then do nothing more then call the first function with the passed arguments for the first function, and then the second function with the arguments for the second function.

Pseudo-C++-Code as example

```
how_is_this_called(f1(x1, x2), f2(y1, y2, y3))
returns ->
    [=] (x1, x2, y1, y2, y3) {
        f1(x1, x2);
        f2(y1, y2, y3);
    }
```

To reduce confusion here is a proper working C++ example of what I'm looking for:

```
// f1 ~ std::function<void(int, String)>
auto f1 = [](int a, String b) {
    cout << "f1: " << a << " - " << b << endl;
};

// f2 ~ std::function<void(String, int)>
auto f2 = [](String a, int b) {
    cout << "f2: " << a << " - " << b << endl;
};


// f ~ std::function<void(int, String, String, int, int, String)>
auto f = how_is_this_called(f1, f2, f1);

f(11, "str1", "str2", 22, 33, "str3");
```

Prints

```
f1: 11 - str1
f2: str2 - 22
f1: 33 - str3
```

Comment: So you want to return a tuple of the two results?

Comment: No, the return value of the "how_is_this_called" function is a new function which calls the two original functions f1 and f2. The C++ syntax may be confusing there

Comment: But usually in functional programming, a function should have *no side effects*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've added a working example in C++ of what I'm looking for. Even if it has side-effects and is not pure functional programming, this operation should still have a name, right? ;-)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this has no name. It also doesn't seem very useful.